# Warning: Attempt to present LastViewController on UINavigationController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue

This is how my app is laid out:

[image: Storyboard layout]

After a timer is done in my second to last view controller I run this code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone_Storyboard" bundle:nil];
LastViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"last"];
vc.value = numberValue;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The last view controller is presented but I get this error message:

```
Warning: Attempt to present LastViewController on UINavigationController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

**EDIT:**

My new layout:

[image: New storyboard layout]

Still getting same error :(

Comment: Is `LastViewController` the last one in the image ? Is it isolated ? Have you defined a segue to it ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless Yes it is. I segue using the code in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view controller's view goes out of a window's view hierarchy when it is no longer displayed. This means that you have presented another view controller over the navigation controller, and it is not in the view hierarchy. When your timer ticks, you attempt to present a view controller on top of the navigation controller.

In your storyboard, you have two navigation controllers and a modal presentation segue. It is likely you have presented the second over the first, and then attempt to present the last view controller over the first.

If you wish to present the last view controller over the top-most presented view controller, you need to keep track of which view controller has been presented. This is a difficult task, and I suggest you consider a small design change for an easier view controller presentation model, or consider several windows model, where the last view controller is displayed as a new window altogether.

Comment: I tried removing the second navigation controller and push segue between the 2nd and 3rd view controller. I still get the error.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique If you present a view controller modally, you will get the same result. You removed the navigation controller, but you display another view controller. It doesn't matter if the view controller is a navigation controller or not.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique As I suggested, you should either track which view controller is at the top and present on that, or find a different way to display.

Comment: The top view controller in my navigation controller?

Comment: @AbdullahShafique Not necessarily. If you `presentViewController:`, that becomes the top, and it can have its own navigation stack. "Top view controller" is an open-ended question which is not easy to solve.

Comment: How can I change my layout to avoid this problem? (Remove navigation controller, change model to push, etc)?

Comment: @AbdullahShafique You need to provide more information about what you are attempting to do. Please update the question and I will edit the answer.